# How to control the Masterpage dropdown options on Sharepoint 2013 composed looks?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, branding

Short of deleting the master page files, is there any way to prevent the default master pages from showing as options in the Change The Look page? I want to give users constrained choices for branding their sites, in order to stay consistent with company branding. Any ideas for how to control this option are appreciated.

I don't want to delete the seattle master page, but I need it to stay in the system as the fallback option for anytime we may need to deactivate our branding feature. Also, the solution must be programmatic and must work as part of an event/feature receiver, as we deal with thousands of such sites.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not appear to be a solution for this. For now, I have decided to leave the default master pages as they are.